# Oauth signature generator failure

Tags: php, symfony, curl

I am using php cURL to PUT some informations (Authorization type: Oauth 1.0), 
my problem is about generate the unique signature using the consumer_secret and access_token and encoded URL  and the '&' also,
I tried to use two methods to generate it but the cURL response is: The signature is invalid. Verify and try again.

this is my last method to generate the signature:

```
// ------------- START GENERATE SIGNATURE -------------
    $oauth = array(
        "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=".$this->consumer_key.",
              oauth_token=".$this->access_token.",
              oauth_signature_method=".$this->signature_method.",
              oauth_timestamp=".$timestimp.",
              oauth_nonce=".$nonce.",
              oauth_version=".$this->version.""
    );
    $base_info = $this->buildBaseString($this->url, 'PUT', $oauth) .'&';
    $composite_key = rawurlencode($this->consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($this->access_token);
    $oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
    // ------------- END GENERATE SIGNATURE -------------
```

and this is the buildBaseString function

```
function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params)
{
    $r = array();
    ksort($params);
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }
    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
}
```

I need help please.
thanks.